# Not able to enter value/click on certain things on a page using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, cheerio, nightmare

Trying to automate few repetitive tasks I do on Google Webmaster Tool and Google Adwords; in both places, I'm getting a little stuck and need help (using Nightmare.js btw)

1) Google Keyword Tool: trying to add value to the text field using JS but not able to make it happen; here's exactly what's going on: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/60846/e8bc4231b7710ac2621aa134fa55b2cb
because i'm not able to enter value using JS, i get the following error when i click the button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmclw.png

2) Google Webmaster Tool: i'm able to navigate to the top pages and top queries section but when i try get Nightmare to click on the 'download this table' button, it does not work; tried doing the same through the console and get undefined: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/60927/78a5a98582f3c271d86ce0786db7210b

Assuming Google is blocking these actions from happening via JS so curious as to how i can solve this

Comment: That's not a good question for StackOverflow, because your question doesn't contain everything to help you and I doubt it is possible to edit your question into shape.

Comment: Here is a thought: Google pages are different depending on user agent and viewport. Try to change those and see if it helps.